# Flutter - how can i update the data to the realtime datebase on firebase and find those keys if i dont know it

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, dart

[image]

I am new to flutter, I am wondering how I can update the data in realtime datebase on firebase if i dont know those keys. 
For example, I want to change the partStatus from "In progress" to "delivered" either dynamically or individually when i dont know those keys.

Comment: Instead of saying what you don't know, tell us what you **do** know about the order(s) that you want to update. Once you do that, it's a matter of firing off a query to find the nodes that have the value you do know, and then updating those nodes by their key.

Comment: For my understanding, I know that I can update those orderlines by using their keys, but are there any ways that I can get those keys? Like i do not know the key "-sSDW3". how can i update the data in this orderline? is there a way to find it in flutter?

Comment: To get the keys, you execute a **query**. See for example my answer here (although not for Flutter): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60252141/delete-entire-record-which-is-associated-with-a-certain-child-value/60253794#60253794

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that whenever you add a new item to your database and autoId has been generated, the **database-generated-id** should be the `id` of the model class you use to hold the data in your project. So whenever an update is made, referencing the `id` as database key can be able to get you to the product you want to update.

See the below sample code:

```
...
//fetching logic here
 Future<void> fetchAndSetOrders() async {
    final url = 'https://<*firebase-project-name*>.firebaseio.com/orderList.json?auth=$authToken';
    //add try and catch errors
    try {
      final response = await http.get(url);
      final responseData = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
      if (responseData == null) {
        return;
      }
      List<OrderItem> loadedOrders = [];
      responseData.forEach(
        (orderId, orderData) => loadedOrders.add(
          OrderItem(
            orderNo: orderData['orderNo'],
            partNo: orderData['partNo'],
            status: orderData['partStatus'],
            qty: orderData['qty'],
            //**here id of order item is the orderId attached to the response 
            id: orderId,
          ),
        ),
      );
      _items = loadedOrders;
      notifyListeners();
    } catch (error) {
      //
    }
  }
...
```

Now to update the order.. since each order has an id equal to the key of the dataitem in the database

```
...
Future<void> updateOrder(String orderId, OrderItem order) async {
    //note that i added the orderId to the url string
    final url = 'https://<*firebase-project-name*>.firebaseio.com/orderList/$orderId.json?auth=$authToken';
    await http.patch(
      url,
      body: json.encode({
        'orderNo': order.orderNo,
        'partNo': order.partNo,
        'partStatus': order.status,
        'qty': order.qty,
      }),
    );
  }
...
```

Happy Coding D:)